# Modifying a Django ModelForms fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I have a Django model, which has a foreign key `owner`, referring to the user who owns this object.
To let other users edit these objects, I currently use a `forms.ModelForm`, which works fine so far.

But I know want to let the owner and only the owner change the owner of the object he owns (what an ownage! :). Thus I tried the following:

```
class FolderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get("instance", False):
            if user == kwargs["instance"].owner:
                self._meta.fields += ("owner",)

        super(FolderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Folder
        fields = (
            "name",
            "description",
        )
```

But this doesn't work, since Django uses some metaclass-magic to set the fields on the model, which seems to be done before my subclassed `__init__` is called.

Anyone ever did something like this?

Comment: Do you need to set owner to user who created the Folder object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use closure normally

```
def make_form(exclude_user=True):
    class Form(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Folder         
            exclude = ['user'] if exclude_user else None
    return Form

form_cls = make_form(request.user != folder.owner)
```

Comment: Works! Fantastic way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create two Forms:

One that excludes owner for users that don't own the data (mouthful) and do a simple if statement in your view:

```
if request.user == Model.owner:
    form = OwnerForm
else:
    form = OthersForm
```

Keep it as simple as possible has HUGE wins down the line.